# Is there any simple way to find out unused Drawable file ,layout and Classes in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-drawable, unused-variables

I have a huge Android project Done with Kotlin . and have many drawable file,Classes and layouts. I wanted to remove unused drawable file,classes and layouts.

Is there any easy way to do so?

Comment: Right-click the project -> Refactor -> Remove Unused Resources

Comment: Is there any possibility to remove Unused selected files only,because some file may use in future.

Comment: You can click preview after clicking "Remove Unused Resources"